# Parse query to fetch records with no value for certain key

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, pfquery

I want to get records where the value for key "Address" is empty as in:

```
var Person = Parse.Object.extend("Person");
var query = new Parse.Query(Person);
query.equalTo("Address", null);
query.equalTo("id", !null);
```

But it is not returning any records. I have also tried `exists`and `notExists` but it doesn't return results as expected.
Please help in getting the query parameters right.

Comment: try using "undefined" in the equal condition

Comment: Neither undefined nor null is correct.  `doesNotExist` is correct.  Try doesNotExist again, and post proof that it doesn't work:  the console output showing the missing object, and a snapshot from the data browser that shows the object that should be found.  Its not that I don't believe you, but posting proof here will help us debug.  (and sometimes will cause the OP to find an error in his/her own thinking).